# ERROR TypeError: "this.posts is undefined" - in an angular type script class

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

I have a type script class in angular as below

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })
export class PostsService {
  private posts: Post[] = [];
  private postsUpdated = new Subject<Post[]>();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getPosts() {
    this.http
      .get<{ message: string; posts: Post[] }>(
        "http://localhost:3000/api/posts"
      )
      .subscribe(postData => {
        this.posts = postData.posts;
        this.postsUpdated.next([...this.posts]);
      });
  }

  getPostUpdateListener() {
    return this.postsUpdated.asObservable();
  }

}
```

In getPosts method I am making a http request to a node server to get data and update the member variable this.posts. But I am getting an error in browser console as below -

**ERROR TypeError: "this.posts is undefined"**

I found out through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback) question on stackoverflow, that this is something to do with the usage of **this** keyword in the callback method. Also I read that my code should work fine since I have used arrow functions. I am not able to get what is leading to the error. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle the case where undefined data will be retrieved from backend.

Just add an OR condition to assign a blank array if backend has no posts.

```
.subscribe(postData => {
        this.posts = postData.posts || [];
        this.postsUpdated.next([...this.posts]);
      });
```

Comment: Thank u :) your answer guided me in spotting the problem area in my code.

Comment: Glad to help you!